# Print out multiple else ifs

Tags: rust

I am working on a program that prints out multiples.

```
fn main(){
   let x = 6;
   if number % 4 == 0 {
      println!("Number is divisble by 4");
   } else if number % 3 == 0 {
       println!("Number is divisble by 3");
   } else if number % 2 == 0 {
       println!("Number is divisble by 2");
   } else {
       println!("Number not divisble by 4, 3, 2, or 1");
   }
}
```

Obviously 3 and 2 are the right answers but this only prints out the first true statement. How can I print out "number is divisble by 3" & "number is divisble by 2" since they are the right answer? I know it is done with match, but I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: Easy, just don't put the ifs in the else.

Comment: Where does `number` come from? What purpose does `x` serve?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing `else if` just have multiple independent `if` blocks. You have to detect the non-divisibility in another way though:

```rust
fn main() {
    let number = 6;
    if number % 4 == 0 {
        println!("Number is divisble by 4");
    }
    if number % 3 == 0 {
        println!("Number is divisble by 3");
    }
    if number % 2 == 0 {
        println!("Number is divisble by 2");
    }
    if number % 2 != 0 && number % 3 != 0 && number % 4 != 0 {
        println!("Number not divisble by 4, 3, or 2");
    }
}
```

I took the liberty of editing out "not divisible by 1", since all numbers are divisible by 1, and replacing `x` by `number`, as I think that's what you intended.

You might reduce the code duplication in the above with a simple loop:

```rust
fn main() {
    let number = 6;
    let mut divisible = false;
    for div in [4, 3, 2] {
        if number % div == 0 {
            println!("Number is divisble by {}", div);
            divisible = true;
        }
    }
    if !divisible {
        println!("Number not divisble by 4, 3, or 2");
    }
}
```

Comment: I was reading the book on the rust main website and it said that we can use match. Do you know of a way to use match to solve this problem. That is my main question.

Comment: @gettingthere24 contrary to C/C++, `match` in rust doesn't fall through, so `match` won't change anything over `if` in solving your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a match statement consider the following:

```
fn main() {
    let x = 6;
    for input in 2..x {
        match x % input {
           0 => println!("{} is a multiple of {}", x, input),
           _ => println!("{} is NOT a multiple of {}", x, input),
        }
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=04e010f83796759c5c24221ba6ad83aa)